# Display channel name in featherjs chat client

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, feathersjs

I am following this [repo](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat) to build a chat application.
I am trying to show the channel name (the default room which users are logged into) in the chat client.

Is there a way to access channel info from

```
const client = feathers();
```

in the [file](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/public/vanilla/app.js)

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not believe so. Channels are a construct on the server side built on top of sockets. Each client are a socket receiving and sending data to the server. On the server sockets/clients can be grouped together into channels, so that you can easily broadcast to many clients, for example:

```
app.channel('authenticated').send({
    warning: "Perimeter has been breached"
  });
```

From what I understand you are trying to create a chat with multiple rooms a.k.a channels. In order to do that you need first to implement the ability to join a specific channel first, this can be done by creating multiple channels on the server, take a look here: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html#example

in your src/channels.js:

```
const { user } = connection;
if (user.room == 'yoyo') {
  app.channel('yoyo').join(connection);
}
```

Then I would recommend to store the room in the user object.
On the client side, when user sign up you could for example do something like this (app.js, line 19):

```
await client.service('users').create(Object.assign({ room: 'yoyo' }, credentials));
```

You could get which room to join from the signup form or perhaps from the path.